# ngTouch breaks forms/input fields

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, hybrid-mobile-app, angularjs-ng-touch

we have a hybrid Angular app which is experiencing the dreaded [300ms delay](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away), even though it should be working (since the correct meta tags have been set).

We tried getting around this issue by using the [FastClick](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/) library and it worked for Safari on iOS and Firefox on Android. But in Chrome on Android the same issue persists.

We tried replacing FastClick by including the [Angular ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) module and it solved *most* of the issues on Chrome.

Now for some reason though, all input fields no longer work. Touching them is being recognised because the CSS of the fields changes, but now we can't enter any data. Long pressing the input makes the cursor appear inside the input field, but the keyboard does not come up on mobile devices. The submit button of the form also no longer works.

This issue is not only visible on mobile devices, but even when using the Chrome Dev Tools to debug locally.

We are using version 1.3.15 of both Angular and Angular-touch.

Here is an example of the login form which we use:

```
        <form name="login_form" class="form" shake submitted="submitted" ng-submit="login(login_form.$valid)" novalidate autocapitalize="none">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="username" required />
        <label placeholder="{{'site.userName' | translate}}"></label>
        <div ng-show="(login_form.name.$invalid && login_form.name.$dirty) || (login_form.name.$pristine && submitted)" class="required">
          <span>{{'login.usernameRequired' | translate}}</span>
        </div>
        <!--<hr class="form-group-separator">-->
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control last-visible-form-control" ng-model="credentials.password" required />
        <label class="responsive" placeholder="{{'site.password' | translate}}"></label>
        <div ng-show="(login_form.password.$invalid && login_form.password.$dirty) || (login_form.password.$pristine && submitted)" class="required">
          <span>{{'login.passwordRequired' | translate}}</span>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>{{'site.stayLoggedIn' | translate}}</label>
            <span class="value">
              <span class="form-check"
                 ng-class="{'checked':credentials.save}"
                 ng-model="credentials.save"
                 ng-click="toggleStayLoggedIn()"></span>  
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <!--<button type="submit"></button>-->
        <button type="submit" class="cta green">
          {{'site.login' | translate}}
          <span data-svg-icon icon="circle-right-arrow"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: By any chance, are the input fields in a modal? (element that is position fixed or absolute)

Comment: Yes, one of the parent containers is absolutely positioned. I tried removing it now, but the input fields still don't work. Also, there are other pages where clickable elements inside an absolutely positioned container work (not input fields though). Do you know of any issues with ngTouch and absolute/fixed positioning?

Comment: Not necessarily with ngTouch, but there are problems on touchscreens when you focus an input. The problem is that mobile browsers zoom in to show you the input and this can cause it to be hidden, or become transparent(this has happened to me in iOS). I've managed to work around this with some JS. However I have used both FastClick and ngTouch and none have caused me problems with inputs.